# How to randomize options/statements?

Tags: c#

So I want to figure out how to randomize statements. So for example you guys know how true and false statements can be the deciding factor of an output? For example:

```
int time = 22;
if (time < 10) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Good morning.");
} 
else if (time < 20) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Good day.");
} 
else 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Good evening.");
}
```

Now using that same example, how would I make so instead of relying on if the time is less than 10 then giving the WriteLine output, it would choose from the 3 chooses and randomly pick one to write in the output?

Comment: `int time = Random.Shared.Next(24);`

Comment: @SirRufo - I thought you were dreaming about `Random.Shared`, but I looked it up and it's there. When did that arrive?

Comment: @Enigmativity As in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-6.0#applies-to) *"Applies to .net Version 6"*

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static Random _random = new Random();

private void YourMethod()
{
    var messages = new[] { "Good morning.", "Good day.", "Good evening." };
    Console.WriteLine(messages[_random.Next(messages.Length)]);
}
```

The `_random` variable is declared only once per thread making this code reliable and thread-safe. You don't have to worry too much about why, but this is a good habit to get into.

---

Alternatively, this works:

```
var messages = new[] { "Good morning.", "Good day.", "Good evening." };
Console.WriteLine(messages[Random.Shared.Next(messages.Length)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are likely hundreds of valid answers but here are two simple solutions to get you started:

#### Random index from array [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9VwmhY)

```cs
// Array of messages
var messages = new [] {
    "Good morning.",
    "Good afternoon.",
    "Good evening."
};

// Random number generator
var randomNumbers = new Random();

// Generate random number within range of 0 to number of messages in array
var randomIndex = randomNumbers.Next(0, messages.Length);

// Choose message at index of random number
var messageAtIndex = messages[randomIndex];

// Display random message
Console.WriteLine(messageAtIndex);
```

#### First from random sorted list ([working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9VwmhY))

```cs
// Array of messages
var messages = new List<string> {
    "Good morning.",
    "Good afternoon.",
    "Good evening."
};

// Random number generator
var randomNumbers = new Random();

// Sort list by random numbers
var randomSortedMessages = messages.OrderBy(x => randomNumbers.Next());

// Choose first message from randomly sorted list
var firstMessage = randomSortedMessages.First();

// Display random message
Console.WriteLine(firstMessage);
```

**Note** that these are *not* the most efficient rather easy to understand solutions with hopes of triggering your creativity.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace TestSo;

internal class TestSo
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var no = rnd.Next(1, 4); // A random number from 1 to 3
        switch (no)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Good morning.");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Good day.");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Good evening.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

See [this ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-6.0#system-random-next(system-int32-system-int32)).